# Evaluating nested queries in sql

Tags: sql

I am a complete beginner in SQL.

Id like to know how to handle nested SQL queries, for example...

```
Query_One = SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Person;
Query_Two = SELECT lastname AS surname FROM (Query_One) NATURAL JOIN Query_One
```

How could I do this in a single statement for example. Is there a way to save the tables individually into a variable maybe?

Comment: Well - your example does not really seem to require a nested query but just: SELECT lastname AS surname FROM Person. So what is it you're trying to achieve which makes you think you need a nested query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT lastname AS surname FROM (SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Person);
```

But as pointed out in the comments, this is not really necessary, `SELECT lastname as surname FROM Person` will do just as well.

Also, a natural join of one table on itself does not make sense.

Comment: Its confusing for me because of the following: A column in the first table is renamed, and then it is joined to what is was before it was renamed. Doesn't that have some sort of affect on the table?

Comment: Are you talking about your code or mine? In mine, nothing is joined on anything. It just projects the results of the two-column inner query down to one column and then renames that column.

Comment: I was talking about mine

Comment: SELECT queries _never_ have write effects on the data they're executed against. And I think you sort of have the order backwards in your comment, the join happens before the renaming. You're just joining Query_One on Query_One, which will simply do - nothing.

Comment: My bad, in my question I tried to make the rename occur first. I tried to do this on SQLFiddle and all it did was add the renamed column to the initial table.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt the following structure. You should be able to embed queries in FROM, although in your example I think that it is not necessary:

```
SELECT p.lastname AS surname FROM (SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Person) p NATURAL JOIN Query_One;
```